# How to set the Default Browser from the Command Line?

Tags: command-line, configuration, browser

Tried to set the default browser using the GUI tools but this didn't work overall. Is there a way to configure the system wide default browser from command line?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Execute the following command in terminal,to change the default browser.

`sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`

**Sample output:**

```
karthick@Ubuntu-desktop:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser 
There are 3 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                    Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/google-chrome   200       auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/firefox         40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome   200       manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/opera           90        manual mode
```

- Press enter to keep the default[*].
- Right now I have **firefox** as my default web browser.
- If i want **google-chrome** as default browser then I will type **3** and hit enter.

**Note:**

- If you want to configure a commandline browser,then you have to configure

  `sudo update-alternatives --config www-browser`
- Alternate way is to add the following line `export BROWSER=/usr/bin/firefox` to your `~/.bashrc`
- Add the above line in the last,

  [image: enter code here]

**Alternative GUI Method:**

- You can also set the default browser in Gnome applications,type the following in terminal and press Enter
  **gnome-default-applications-properties**
- It will Open a Window.Now you can choose your preferred browser to set it default.
  [image]

Comment: My gnome-www-browser is a link to epiphany, my x-www-browser is a link to chromium, but the right click in the terminal (gnome-terminal and terminator) opens the url with firefox :(

Comment: Is there command line for to set  document viewer as default for PDF.

Comment: This doesn't work for Ubuntu 18.04. The answer from stilllife works: 
`xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium-browser.desktop`

Answer (score 31):

The already suggested methods might not work for some app (e.g. HipChat).

I've had to do:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium-browser.desktop
```

Comment: XFCE seems to set this with it's GUI Settings -> Preferred applications

Comment: This helped me set the default browser for `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Worked for me in Debian 10. I've downloaded Firefox 85, untargziped into `/lib/firefox`, created `.desktop` file into `/usr/share/applications/` but it is not appearing into Default Browsers choices in GNOME settings. This above command works well in this case.

Answer (score 4):

It depends a bit on what "default browser" exactly means, i.e. for what purpose you want to change the browser. Some programs ignore any system-wide settings and use their own settings.

That said, you can set the default browser for all programs starting the browser with the generic `sensible-browser` command by exporting the `BROWSER` variable, e.g. add a line to the file `~/.bashrc`:

```
export BROWSER=/usr/bin/firefox
```

The other generic way of calling a browser is `x-www-browser`, this one is handled by the Debian "alternatives" system:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

If you want to configure a commandline-only browser like *lynx*, you have to configure `www-browser` instead.

Answer (score 4):

**Googlers**, to do this fully scripted (no interaction whatsoever) in a setup script:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome 500
sudo update-alternatives --set x-www-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

…and similary for your favorite editor:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/pluma 500
sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/pluma
```

Comment: what does 500 stand for?

Comment: it's just a “sufficently high“ (but mostly guessed) [priority value](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) to “win” over all existing.

Comment: Didn't work for me when I tried /home/myusernam/.helper_scripts/browser_wrapper where the wrapper just does: vivaldi-stable --new-window --force-device-scale-factor=2 $@ 2>/dev/null, I get a message: [49696:49722:0226/123433.848972:ERROR:bus.cc(398)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix").  So nice to have these GUI that just ignore BROWSER

Answer (score 2):

The top two answers here both look promising, yet only one of them worked for me. Have you ever wondered why? For the sake of completeness, this is an [official wiki page from Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DefaultWebBrowser#Foreign_applications):

> ### Foreign applications
>
> #### Default for foreign programs (system-wide)
>
> Programs which are not designed for the user's desktop environment do not obey the browser settings of the desktop environment (GNOME or KDE). For example, Thunderbird ignores desktop environment-specific browser settings. The default browser for generic applications can be changed for the whole system by reconfiguring the x-www-browser alternative.
>
> ```
> # update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
> ```
>
> #### Default for foreign programs (user-specific)
>
> Some applications use xdg-open (part of [xdg-utils](http://packages.debian.org/stable/xdg-utils)). xdg-settings can be used to both get and change the default browser. Local settings can also be found in the users' home in ~/.config/mimeapps.list.
>
> ```
> $ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
> chromium.desktop
>
> $ xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox-esr.desktop
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`

only shows installed application trough apt-get, for manual installation you can use

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /opt/yourapp/yourapp 200
sudo update-alternatives --set x-www-browser /opt/yourapp/yourapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
sudo update-alternatives --config www-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional to those answer google-chrome has usually a symbolic link to the channel-specific version:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome -> /etc/alternatives/google-chrome -> /usr/bin/google-chrome-beta
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, today, running Gnome 3, `~/.config/mimeapps.list` is what controls `gnome-open <url>` and Java's `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url))`.  This is what changes there when I run `gnome-control-center` (the "Details" applet in the settings application from the top right menu) and change Default Applications, Web from Google Chrome to Firefox ESR:

```
11c11
< x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
---
> x-scheme-handler/http=firefox-esr.desktop`
```

As hoped, I could revert that from the command line with:

`perl -i -wpe 's@x-scheme-handler/http(s?)=firefox-esr.desktop@x-scheme-handler/http$1=google-chrome.desktop@' ~/.config/mimeapps.list`

... and put it back with:

`perl -i -wpe 's@x-scheme-handler/http(s?)=google-chrome.desktop@x-scheme-handler/http$1=firefox-esr.desktop@' ~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Comment: Looks like this is the file that `xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop` updates.

Comment: For me that seems to be replacing .local/share/applications/mimeapps.list... with the same content it already has.  Something's broken but perhaps it's just for me.

Answer (score -1):

For me, `sensible-browser` seems to just call `/usr/bin/gnome-www-browser`, which symlinks to `/etc/alternatives/gnome-www-browser`, which symlinks to the browser. To change it, I needed to do this:

```
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/gnome-www-browser
sudo ln -s ~/bin/firefox /etc/alternatives/gnome-www-browser
```

You should put the full path to the browser that you want to use in place of `~/bin/firefox`.

Now, when I run `sensible-browser https://example.com`, Firefox opens as expected.