# Installation of google-chrome overrides preferences for 'default browser'

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

After I've installed google-chrome (***not*** chromium), I noticed that it completely overwrote any behaviour set for the default browser, thus resulting in any link clicked in the GNOME environment being opened in Chrome, instead of my *actual* default browser, Firefox.

Just about *any* browser I know, Including Opera, Midori, Rekonq, Dillo, Icecat (and a bunch of others) honor the 'default browser' settings, *WITHOUT* screwing around with global .desktop files.

Even after manually searching for everything possibly related in gconf-editor, I was not able to get rid of this behaviour, and restore firefox as the default browser, so help is very much appreciated.

---

PS: Please spare me your "*why don't you just switch to chrome instead?*" - I have my reasons, and this is certainly not the place to discuss them!

Comment: a terminal method that is not limited to unity and gnome: http://askubuntu.com/a/16626/47206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the Unity button (top-left) and type and click on **Preferred Applications**. In the Internet tab you'll be able to choose the Default Web browser you want.

[image: screenshot_preferred_applications]

Comment: (i'm running ubuntu-classic, instead of unity, but the settings are virtually the same) Hah, you beat me to it. Why hasn't that occured to me yet? I feel soo stupid right now...

Comment: @hiobs Happens sometimes, don't feel bad about it :) And thanks for the accept btw

Comment: hahaha okay :-) and you're very welcome!