# Stop Google Chrome being the default browser in Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set the Default Browser from the Command Line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16621/how-to-set-the-default-browser-from-the-command-line)

Due to an issue presented [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/225569/47206) I was inclined to use Google Chrome instead of Chromium.

I have set Firefox as the default browser and disabled that in Google Chrome, but the latter keeps opening the links in Office Writer (for example).

It is the same issue as [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/64032/47206), except that here I use Lubuntu, and the answer there is for Gnome/Unity, and I do not have that settings.

Or do I?

Comment: See if this [helps](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16621/how-to-set-the-default-browser-from-the-command-line). In other words, the current question may be a duplicate.

Comment: @vasa1: thnx. i had just found an answer on ubuntuforums. i will close this as duplicate. but would you consider looking at this question and giving a vote to reopen? http://askubuntu.com/q/223557/47206 - it looks like duplicate because of the limited answer, but i ask for more answers that i cannot get as the question is closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1607996).

Fire in Terminal

`sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`

enter password, see something like this

[image]

Type the number of your default browser of choice and then enter.

That's it.