# How to set Iron as default web browser in Unity2D?

Tags: unity, 12.04, default-programs, default-browser

I use Iron as my default browser, but in Unity i did not found the place, where i could set it as default for my user. In System settings is Preferred Applications, but in list of web browsers is just Firefox (but my Iron is installed through te package manager). How to add Iron to this list?

So i searched a while, but did still not found the solution.

In this [posting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16621/how-to-set-the-default-browser-from-the-command-line) i saw good idea how to set default browser system-wide, but again, Iron wasn't in the list of available browsers.

So, how to make Iron default browser in Unity(2D)? Desirably user-based way, not system wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a way to make Iron system-wide default:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/iron/iron /etc/alternatives/x-www-browser
```