# Cannot set Opera as default browser

Tags: browser

I've tried to set Opera as my default browser in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I've tried in Opera's settings, and in the Ubuntu System Settings. I hit all the right buttons in both paces, but it just doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Is there a Terminal command that'll make it work?

Comment: Did you restart after setting it ?

Comment: Does this help - http://askubuntu.com/a/16626/626243 ?