# Setting default web-browser for CLI

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04

How can I set the default web-browser on Ubuntu / Kubuntu 22, so it is also used by commands I run from the CLI?

I have installed Chromium as a Flatpak, and set it to the default web-browser using the KDE desktop, but it is apparently not respected by programs I run from the command-line.

Specifically, when I run the command `jupyter notebook` it starts Firefox instead of Chromium. I know I can change that in jupyter's config-file, but I would like to change it in Kubuntu's config instead, so it is always respected by all applications.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like all the options are listed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16621/how-to-set-the-default-browser-from-the-command-line

Comment: Thanks. I've tried some of the solutions suggested there and they don't seem to work. I'm thinking that maybe it is because I installed Chromium using Flatpak and Kubuntu 22 is setup to use Snap. Maybe it is possible by editing some config files. But rather than destroying something and having to reinstall everything, I think I'll just live with the inconvenience and hope it gets fixed in a future release of Kubuntu.