# Slack ignores default browser in Linux

Tags: firefox, chromium, browser, default-browser, slack

The problem has already been stated [elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/bv7sx1/slack_ignores_default_browser_in_linux/):

> 8 Posted by u/fractalchemist 4 years ago Slack ignores default browser
> in Linux
>
> I'm using Kubuntu linux, and prior to the upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04
> Slack used my default browser (Chrome). After the update, it only
> opens links in Firefox. Slack is the only app that does this.
>
> Everything else opens in Chrome. Chrome is set as my default and the
> same in .config/mimeapps.list
>
> It's driving me nuts, and now it's costing me work as one of the
> companies I work with has a "claim" button for jobs that I cannot
> access. There's no "right-click and copy address" in Slack from these
> buttons.

I saw nothing in slack preferences for setting a [specific](https://askubuntu.com/q/16621/847449) browser.

For myself, I prefer Firefox over Chromium.

---

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ strings $(type -p Slack) | grep -E '^[A-Z]+$'
```

This command just hangs.  Run this from the console?

Comment: See if your Slack executable uses environment variables with `strings $(type -p Slack) | grep -E '^[A-Z]+$'` or if it uses hard-coded paths with `strings $(type -p Slack) | grep -E '^/[a-z]+/'`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.

Comment: What is `xdg-settings get default-web-browser`?